# What online resources or eBook explains tensor analysis clearly

Tags: reference-request, tensors, statistical-mechanics

I would like recommendations for online resources or ebooks that explain tensor analysis in non-technical terms. Most of the resources I have seen are really technical (and unintuitive in some cases).

Comment: What do you want to get from this book? Or rather what kind of concepts you want to understand? And also although I believe one can give a vague explanation of what the tensor is without technical terms, I doubt that *tensor analysis* can be explained in a similar way.

Comment: Maybe [**Tensor Geometry: The Geometric Viewpoint and its Uses**](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-3-642-10514-2/mode/2up) by Dodson/Poston.